# How to replace Linux Kernel error messages with my defined error messages?

Tags: c, linux, error-handling, arguments, kernel

I have created a shell and when I give wrong number of arguments like insufficient arguments to `cp` commands I receive the Linux shell error message like what you will receive if you type `cp fork.c` as follows:

```
mysh> cp fork.c
cp: missing destination file operand after `fork.c'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

How can I bypass this error message and print my own error message like `Dude! this is an error` ?

Comment: the message doesn't come from kernel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp fork.c > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Dude! this is an error"
```

Comment: This was such a neat answer! I really liked it!

Answer (score 1):

That message is generated by the `cp` command, not by the kernel or the shell. You would need to either reimplement the `cp` command yourself or capture and replace its output to change the message, but neither of these is really an appropriate thing for a shell to do.

Comment: How can I  capture and replace each command's output to change the message??